# Is the torchvision MNIST loader not working properly or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, mnist, pytorch

I wanted to see that the images I used in my network were OK, so I saved a bunch of them using the following code:

```
train_set = dset.MNIST(root=root, train=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor(), download=download)

for it, (img, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    X = Variable(img)
    tar = Variable(target)
    X = X.view(batch_size, -1)
    cur_img_batch = X.data.numpy()
    cur_tar_batch = tar.data.numpy()
    for i in range(batch_size):
        cur_img = cur_img_batch[i]
        im = Image.fromarray(cur_img.reshape((28, 28)).astype('uint8') * 255)
        if cur_tar_batch[i] == 8:
            im.save(test_img_dir + 'iter_' + str(it) + '_sample_' + str(i) + '.png')
```

This isn't the cleanest code, but it just saves a bunch of images that are all labeled as '8'. Upon opening them, I see that most of them look like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjjtb.png), even though a small minority of them are perfectly [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEzbg.png).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This line `cur_img.reshape((28, 28)).astype('uint8') * 255` Are you converting the data to integer before multiplying it by 255?

Comment: Of course! This was it - thanks a lot :)

Comment: The correct line should be:             im = Image.fromarray((cur_img.reshape((28, 28)) * 255).astype('uint8'))

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

The issue was in this line `cur_img.reshape((28, 28)).astype('uint8') * 255`, converting the normalized image to integer before multiplying it by 255, thus resulting in images with either 0 or 255.

The updated code:

```
train_set = dset.MNIST(root=root, train=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor(), download=download)

for it, (img, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    X = Variable(img)
    tar = Variable(target)
    X = X.view(batch_size, -1)
    cur_img_batch = X.data.numpy()
    cur_tar_batch = tar.data.numpy()
    for i in range(batch_size):
        cur_img = cur_img_batch[i]
        im = Image.fromarray((cur_img.reshape((28, 28)) * 255).astype('uint8'))
        if cur_tar_batch[i] == 8:
            im.save(test_img_dir + 'iter_' + str(it) + '_sample_' + str(i) + '.png')
```